# Undo sorting of multidimensional numpy array along specific axis

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am sorting a large multidimensional numpy array along an axis.
After some computations I'd like to undo the sorting with the values themselves being different to when I did the initial sorting.

Initially I tried by simply reversing the sorting indices, but if the array was already sorted correctly in the first place this of course doesn't make any sense, see below code.

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(100,2,4)
array.out = array

arg = array.argsort(axis=1)
arg_rev = arg.argsort(axis=1)

# this solution is based on https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4724

for i in range(0, array.shape[2]):
    tmp = array[:,:,i]
    array.out[:,:,i] = tmp[np.arange(np.shape(tmp)[0])[:, np.newaxis],  arg_ftc_rev[:,:,i]]
```

I would like to combine this solution with the one from [undo or reverse argsort(), python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483696/undo-or-reverse-argsort-python) without having to loop over an additional array index.

```py
# ( a = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
# aa = np.argsort(a)
# aaa = np.argsort(aa) )
# e.g.
array.out[:,:,i] = tmp[np.arange(np.shape(tmp)[0])[:, np.newaxis],  arg_ftc[:,:,i][arg_ftc_rev[:,:,i]]
```

but this does not work, as it results in the wrong shape.

Comment: "Undo sorting after changing values" is a pretty nebulous concept.  Can you provide an example (with data) of what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: Use the `inverse_permutation` function at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535723/1782792) to invert the result of argsort.

Comment: @jdehesa I tried
```python
import numpy as np

array = np.random.rand(100,2,4)

arg = array.argsort(axis=1)
x = inverse_permutation(arg)
```

but there is an error because it cannot broadcast.

Comment: @ScottHunter I mean that the position of each element along the sorting axis should be as to begin with, however the values within these will have been modified. Simply sorting again is thus no option

e.g.
```python
x = [1, 3, 1, 6]
x = sort(x)
# [1, 1, 3, 6]
x = x*2
# [2, 2, 6, 12]
# undo sorting
# [2, 6, 2, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake

`array.out[:,:,i] = tmp[np.arange(np.shape(tmp)[0])[:, np.newaxis],  arg_ftc[:,:,i][arg_ftc_rev[:,:,i]]`

needs to be

`array.out[:,:,i] = tmp[np.arange(np.shape(tmp)[0])[:, np.newaxis], [arg_ftc_rev[:,:,i]]`